# 3 monitors setup requirements

Tags: multiple-monitors, gpu

What is the requirement for a GPU to be able to handle 3 monitors? I am NOT asking for a specific model, I am asking technically. What kind of power/output/any other technology does it have to have?

Comment: Power is largely irrelevant to how many monitors it can support. It is entirely dependant on the GPU being able to support 3 or more monitors and the manufacturer having wired up the relevant connections.

Comment: Just purchase a GPU that in the product specifications indicates it can output to 3 monitors.  At the end of the day that's the only thing that matters.

Comment: @Ramhound I am perfectly aware of that (my current gpu can) I am asking out of curiosity and interest as what is the technical challenge in outputting to 3 monitors

Comment: The only technical challenge is the hardware supports it.

Comment: I think it had something to do with the RAMDAC but it's been so long since I've researched this in-depth. You can read this post to get started: http://www.overclock.net/t/721931/active-vs-passive-displayport-adapters-the-truth

Comment: If you are trying to do triple monitors off of an onboard GPU then display port to triple DVI converters might be of interest to you. Since display port is a packet-based display technology, it is actually able to intelligently route which port a signal goes to, kind of like TCP/IP works.